# How to set a specific input method to a file

Tags: emacs

I write in several languages, and I would like to define a different input method for different files.  Is there a way to do this?

(For example, to set a specific dictionary, at the end of a file I write the following:

```
<!-- Local IspellDict: british -->
```

Can I do something similar for input methods?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this at the beginning of the file:

```
-*- eval: (activate-input-method 'latin-4-postfix); -*-
```

Or at the end of the file:

```
Local Variables:
eval: (activate-input-method 'latin-4-postfix)
End:
```

In either case, you can/should comment the lines if the major mode has a comment syntax.

If you just want to select which input method will be enabled if you type <kbd>C-\</kbd> then instead of:

```
eval: (activate-input-method 'latin-4-postfix)
```

you would use:

```
default-input-method: latin-4-postfix
```

Comment: The first two pieces of code answered my question. Thank you @phils ! However, I tried to use the last one, just out of curiosity, but I didn't manage to get it to work. I got this message: _File local-variables error: (void-function default-input-method)_. It's maybe that I'd need something else in my init file for it to work.

Comment: Note that the difference in syntax between the examples I gave was not a mistake. The `default-input-method` example should not use `eval` or parentheses.

Comment: To clarify, it's the difference between giving the variable `default-input-method` a file-local value, or using the *pseudo-variable* `eval` to *call a function*.