# How to set a specific input method to emacs specific major-mode?

Tags: input, emacs, major-mode

I use few languages and I need to set up *specific input method to specific major-mode* in Emacs.

I mean, configuration to "auto change" input method for specific major-mode.

Is there some way to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MODE-hook for each MODE in question to either set the `default-input-method` (toggled with <kbd>C-\</kbd>) for buffers in that mode:

```el
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'my-emacs-lisp-mode-hook)
(defun my-emacs-lisp-mode-hook ()
  "Custom behaviours for `emacs-lisp-mode'."
  (setq-local default-input-method "latin-1-prefix"))
```

or to go ahead and *activate* the input method automatically:

```el
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'my-emacs-lisp-mode-hook)
(defun my-emacs-lisp-mode-hook ()
  "Custom behaviours for `emacs-lisp-mode'."
  (activate-input-method "latin-1-prefix"))
```

See also [How to set a specific input method to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45893232).